# Inconsolata/zi4 font issue MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex

Okay, so everything was fine previously. But when I re-installed my machine and thereby also MiKTeX and my beloved TeXstudio my old documents complain on:

```
\usepackage{inconsolata}
```

No worries, it's not gone, just seems replaced:

```
\usepackage{zi4}
```

Although now I get the following errors:

```
Trying to make PK font ot1-zi4r-0 at 600 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe... miktex-makemf: The ot1-zi4r- source file could not be found.
Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk: PK font ot1-zi4r-0 could not be created.
```

Tried all the `initexmf` tricks etc, nothing works... But then I've been looking around in the [CTAN archive](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata/doc) and found the following trick in the documentation file:

```
\pdfmapfile{+zi4.map}
\usepackage{zi4}
```

Can anybody explain to me:

- Why doesn't the font work out-of-the-box?
- Why and how does the `\pdfmapfile` trick work?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run updmap (or initexmf --mkmaps which is the same) in a command line as user(!) ?

Answer (score 6):

I guess you installed MiKTeX as basic version?  The basic version has not all packages included you need.

In the MikTeX package manager you will find a package `inconsolata` including all you need.

In the readme of this package you can read:

> Copy the Inconsolata-zi4.tds.zip to the root of the folder you use for 
>   personal additions to the TeX trees, open a command window, chdir to that 
>   folder, and type
>
> unzip Inconsolata-zi4.tds

This all should be done with the package manger. For me I could use the font directly after instalation with the package manager, but perhaps there was an error on your system. So proceed as told in the readme:

> initexmf --update-fndb
>
> initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
>
> The latter command should open updmap.cfg in your default editor,
>   commonly Notepad. Add the line
>
> Map zi4.map
>
> to updmap.cfg, save and close. Then, in the command window, type
>
> initexmf --mkmaps
>
> You can ignore error messages that may occur here. This should result in a properly enabled garamondx.

The "`\pdfmapfile` trick work" is just a workaround for the proper installation of the font.  You should complete the font installation.

This is a longer version of the comment @UlrikeFischer wrote.