# Use of fdsymbol package produces pixelated symbols

Tags: fonts, bitmap

The following Latex code produces a large curvy image of the subset-symbol:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\subset$
\end{document}
```

If I now add the following to the preamble,

```
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
```

then the produced image becomes very pixelated, as if using a bitmap font. Why does this happen, and can it be fixed?

Edit: Here's an image of the pixelated symbol.

[image: Pixelated subset symbol]

Comment: check the fonts in the resulting pdf with pdffonts utility of acrobat font menu, on your example using fdfonts I get `ANSIVE+FdSymbolB-Book                Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0` so type1 not bitmap font is used

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cdt5V.png) is the image I get.

Comment: Without fdsymbol: `DSUYQS+CMSY10 Type 1 Builtin yes yes no 4 0`. With fdsymbol: `[none] Type 3 Custom yes no no 4 0`.

Comment: Let me guess: are you on MiKTeX?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I have MikTeX 2.9, which I updated yesterday, on Windows 10.

Comment: Try following the instructions in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128177/4427 with `fdsymbol.map` instead of `zi4.map`.

Comment: @egreg: Adding `\pdfmapfile{fdsymbol.map}` works; I have a curvy symbol again. Can it be made to work without it?

Comment: @Kaba I was meaning the `initexmf` and `updmap` commands in Kurt's answer.

Comment: @egreg: Using initexmf the problem is now solved (great!), although I do not understand why.

Comment: @Kaba I've seen several times problems like this: when font packages are upgraded or added to MiKTeX, it can happen that the map file that associates to TeX fonts their Type1 counterpart is not updated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments