# Is (( \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} )) responsible for the python font in PDF code cells?

Tags: pdftex, sourcecode, preamble

I'd like to make my PDFs stand out so I'm trying to change the default Python font that gets used in the code cells when exporting PDFs with [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I was exploring in `article.tplx` and found that I could add this block to the preamble to change all of the notebook text.

```
((*- block docclass -*))
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
((*- endblock docclass -*))
```

Everything looks great with the sans serif in **markdown**, but the ugly serif font in the python **code cells** still persists.

I found out that font is one of [Donald Knuth's](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~rwest/wikispeedia/wpcd/wp/d/Donald_Knuth.htm) original fonts for his TeX typesetting system called [Computer Modern Teletype Italic](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computermodernteletype/). Documentation says it's used like this `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

So low and behold I found that line in `base.lptx`.

```
((*- block header -*))
    ((* block docclass *))\documentclass[11pt]{article}((* endblock docclass *))

    ((* block packages *))
    \usepackage{iftex}
    \ifPDFTeX
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \else
        \usepackage{fontspec}
    \fi
```

But I really don't know what I'm doing. How can I replace this default Python font with a sans serif font in the code cells of the exported Jupyter PDFs?

[image]

Comment: fontenc is not related. If you don't want itshape there you will probably have to change the settings for listings or whatever is setting the code.

Comment: Thanks. If I knew what or where that was I wouldn't need to post here lol  :)

Comment: well I won't start to investigate the templates in some large external system that I don't have. Search for listings or minted in the code. Or ask the maintainer of this system how to adjust this font.

Comment: Yup, already did that. Haven't got a reply. I have checked all the templates but there is no way of knowing what tex lines are responsible for the python code in Jupyter code cells. Even the part I guessed correctly with the `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` how on earth is that responsible for the Jupyter markdown since there is no mention of Jupyter and/or markdown anywhere in the tplx? I don't know how it all gets connected.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also since `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is exactly the Python Computer Modern Teletype` font as per the doc I posted, how do you know that that is not responsible for the python in the code cells? You seem to know what is placed where.

Comment: I know if because I know something about latex and how it handles fonts. Look up my profile if you want. fontenc changes the font encoding not the font type.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so if the documentation says `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` - `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style` Is there any useful info there that I can glean? Ok so for example, how or where is `\usepackage{helvet}` - `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` in article.tplx setting the Jupyter markdown?

Comment: you can try `\renewcommand\ttfdefault{phv}`, but then the typewriter font will no longer be a monospaced font.

Comment: Ok I will try that. What do you mean it will no longer be a monospaced font and why would that matter? What is `phv`? Also I found this. What do you make of this python.tpl file? https://imgur.com/M1Qp7Yj

Comment: ah I understand. Just read that monospace fonts are good for code and sans serif for large volumes of text. Well can I use a monospace font that is not serif? How on earth could an ugly font with tons of curves be good for code? When I use another IDE like VS Code there are using nice fonts for code not that serif stuff.

Comment: for example I just checked this wiki.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces . Losts of nice monospace sans serif fonts for code like Droid, and Inconsolata. Inconsolata Is very famous for coders. I would like to use that. Or would be happy even with Monaco. And as it turns out Monaco is used for many Jupyter Notebook CSS themes. But those are not related to these PDF exports unfortunately.

Comment: This Tex code in the imgur `python.tpl` screenshot I linked to has peaked my interest. `{% block input %}
{{ cell.source | ipython2python }}
{% endblock input %}`

Comment: I received some shell errors which intrigued me so I checked in `usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/` and found some font related files like `t1cmtt.fd`. Going back to the Computer Modern Teletype link it seems that `t1cmtt` could refer to `Computer Modern Teletype`. When I open it up it it has `\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{n}{ectt}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{sl}{ecst}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{it}{ecit}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{sc}{ectc}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}%` and `original source files:
%%
%% cmfonts.fdd `

Comment: Inconsolata can be used with the zi4 package.

Comment: Sorry, Ulrike. I have no idea what zi4 is so I checked this tex question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126259/inconsolata-zi4-font-issue-miktex. But I have no idea how I can apply it. I unzip it in the same folder as article.tplx? And then how do I know if I am changing the code cell font?

Comment: The `tex/latex/psnfss/` folder seems interesting. It has a bunch of `sty` and `fd` fonts. Maybe I put Inconsolata in there?

Comment: Ah, it seems I am correct. In the Inconsolata zip folder there is a tex folder and in that there are `, inconsolatan.fontspec, inconsolata.sty, ly1zi4.fd, zi4.sty, ts1zi4.fd`. etc. It seems those go in `tex/latex/psnfss/` with all the other `sty / fd fonts`. So if I put them in there then how do I make them work with thise whole thing I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Inconsolata can be used in LaTeX like this. The font is normally included in a normal tex installation. There is no slanted version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{zi4}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
# pyplot
import pandas
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok one second. I have to set this up first. Inconsolata install instructions says. https://imgur.com/6DqurAe. So I guess I cannot just drop them in there. I don't have a TDS folder though. I can create this directory no problem. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c`. Where did you put your Inconsolata files? And your posted answer code. Where does it go? in the article.tplx?

Comment: you already have a tex system. After all you can use fonts. So why do you think that you need to install something additionally? I hadn't to do anything, the font was already there.

Comment: ok the code you posted. Does it go in article.tplx? What is this part? `\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
# pyplot
import pandas` Why is `# pyplot 
import pandas` there? Tex needs this?

Comment: I would add `\usepackage{zi4}` below the `\usepackage{helvet}` that you added already, but I have no idea how your system works and how you should setup its template and I will not try to find out more details.

Comment: ok thank you very much. I will check around. After I have tested I will come back.